# What's needed to compile in a sdk version

Tags: java, android, gradle, sdk

I am compiling an example app that have this gradle configuration:

```
minsdkversion: 18
targetsdkversion: 19
```

So I install the APO 18,19 but the compiler throws me an error:

```
Where:
Build file '/Users/sergio/Downloads/kickflip-android-sdk-master/sdk/build.gradle' line: 137

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':sdk'.
The SDK directory '~/Library/Android/sdk' does not exist.
Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

[image: capture of android sdk manager]

So my question is, as a newbie android developer, which tools apart from the API/SDK I have to install to compile an app in a specific version.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property `sdk.dir` in `local.properties` in your project points to the wrong folder:

```
The SDK directory '~/Library/Android/sdk' does not exist.
```

If you use Android Studio it should automatically set the property to the correct location.

Comment: Be more specific: What does your `local.properties` contain? Can you use `cd` in a shell to go to the directory specified in `local.properties`?

Comment: Yes if i do cd it exist it works in all apps except this one

Comment: As which user do you compile this application? Is it the same user as used for the other applications? If not, you would either have to install the Android SDK for this user too, or move the Android SDK to a folder accessible by these two (or all) users.

Comment: I dont have a local.properties file. It uses the path dir. Its the same enviroment and same user.

Comment: Then add `local.properties` to folder `/Users/sergio/Downloads/kickflip-android-sdk-master` and add property `sdk.dir` to it. Use the full path to the Android SDK for its value. I am guessing the value should be `/Users/sergio/Library/Android/sdk`. If that does not work, I don't have a clue what could be causing the problems.

Comment: I tried that before asking here, and It didn't work, so I dont have a clue too, so thanks for all.